# Python 2 Remote-Container Config Not available?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Getting started with developing on remote containers on a windows machine and have set up on WSL2 and using Remote-Containers/Docker. I have found an Python 2.7 project I want to look at however the Remote-Container config files do not appear to be available (just python3).  I've installed both 3.8 and 2.7 on WSL2.

I understand Python 2 is no longer supported but I've seen numerous tutorials (mostly 6mos-1yr old) where python 2.7 config files exist so I'm a bit lost on why its not listed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: Please check whether there are Python2 environment variables in your WSL2.

Comment: New to Linux and WSL2 so I haven't quite sorted out how to get/set the env variables. My plan is to avoid having Python installed directly onto my machine but rather pull the Docker image in my remote container. Good news is that by modifying the default Python3 Dockerfile, its building the Python2 image correctly.  Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround - simply editing the Dockerfile worked.

Comment: Initially did not help, I even used the same Dockerfile they previously had for python2 github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/pull/195/files - when starting the dev container it saucily started a python3 container (mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:0-3.7) without even asking if I'd be okay with that (I am not, and the 13 year old code is in no way compatible with python3). What helped was removing the comments in the Dockerfile, deleting the python3 image and then forcing a rebuild of the dev container. Maybe they "fallback" to 3 if they see the same hash of their 2 config ‍♀️